# How to read a PHP file as text file to an array?

Tags: php

Here is my situation.Supposing I have a PHP file named as:

```
myfunctions.php
```

Is it possible to read the contents of that PHP file (myfunctions.php) in another script using available PHP functions?

I'm using the following functions without success in reading this PHP file:

```
file_get_contents()
file()
```

It simply returned blank. One of the possible successful method was to read this PHP file as text file but I do not know how to do this..If someone has some other methods, please share. Ideally I want the output to be an array so the data I would like to obtain will be easily manipulated for use.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want the contents of the file or the *interpreted* contents? If the first, `file()` will work just fine. If it doesn't there is problably an error somewhere else.

Comment: @NiravRanpara *I'm using the following functions without success...* that's what the OP tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I will change the extension on the "myfunctions.php" to "myfunctions.txt" and use the theses functions

```
file_get_contents()
file()
```

But I don't know if you are allow to change the name of the document.

```
file() - Reads entire file into an array
fgets() - Gets line from file pointer
fread() - Binary-safe file read
readfile() - Outputs a file
file_put_contents() - Write a string to a file
stream_get_contents() - Reads remainder of a stream into a string
stream_context_create() - Creates a stream context
```

Answer (score 0):

You need [fread](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php). To put it into an array, you might look at [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)