# PHP IMAP authenticate my credentials and give me good and bad login in txt

Tags: php, imap

I have a PHP IMAP code I wrote that makes me manually type in my email and password to validate/authenticate. If I input a wrong password it gives me "not connect" and if I type in my right password it displays "CONNECT".

```
<?php
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$domcom = trim(strstr($email, '@'), '@');
$mbox = imap_open("{mail.$domcom:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert/notls}", "user@domain.com", "password");
if ($mbox == true)
{
   echo "CONNECT";
}
else
{
   echo "NOT CONNECT";
}
?>
```

So what I need is I don't want to manually type it myself again. I need help with fixing the script for it to do the work automatically, that I have my email:password like this in a log.txt file in the format below:

```
user1@domain.com:password1 
user2@domain.com:password2
user3@domain.com:password3
user4@domain.com:password4
use5@domain.com:password5
use6@domain.com:password6
use7@domain.com:password7 
user8@domain.com:password8
user9@domain.com:password9
user10@domain.com:password10 
user11@domain.com:password11
user12@domain.com:password12
```

So, if I run the imap.php script on browser it checks them automatically line by line till it finishes, and gives me "good.txt" for authenticated login that connects and "bad.txt" for bad login.

Note: I want the IMAP server in quote "" to remain the same.

`{mail.$domcom:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert/notls}`

Make `$domcom` call the domain part in each line of the txt and post it on the IMAP server line of code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14601650/how-to-read-a-php-file-as-text-file-to-an-array

Comment: _"someone that can add the remaining script"_ That's not how this works. We'll help you if you get stuck but we're not going to do your work for you. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**What topics can I ask about here?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly put below code in your imap.php

```
<?php

$lines = file('log.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

foreach($lines as $line){
    list($email, $password) = explode(':', $line);

    $domcom = trim(strstr($email, '@'), '@');
    $mbox   = imap_open("mail.{$domcom}:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert/notls", $email, $password);
    if( $mbox == true ){
        file_put_contents('good.txt', $line."\n", FILE_APPEND);
    }else{
        file_put_contents('bad.txt', $line."\n", FILE_APPEND);
    }
}
    
?>
```

And below in the log.txt

```
user1@domain.com:password1
user2@domain.com:password2
user3@domain.com:password3
user4@domain.com:password4
use5@domain.com:password5
use6@domain.com:password6
use7@domain.com:password7
user8@domain.com:password8
user9@domain.com:password9
user10@domain.com:password10
user11@domain.com:password11
user12@domain.com:password12
```

Source

`file()` - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

`file_put_contents()` - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: IT WORKED LIKE MAGIC THANK YOU MAN

Comment: i'm very grateful man <3

Comment: My pleasure. Kindly consider marking it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @rudeboy21 i already did many times i get  "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."

Comment: @Steve Conder I don't mean "upvote". "To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in."